# How to enter tilde (~), back tick (`) and special chars with a non-US keyboard?

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc, keyboard-layout

I usually use Vim with an Italian keyboard (I'm from Italy), 
(mainly in an Ubuntu Linux Virtualbox guest from a Windows host).

I have problems when I have to enter some frequently used characters (in Unix) not present in Italian keyboard layout, I'm referring especially to these chars:

- tilde: <kbd>~</kbd> (home directory alias)
- back quote / back tick: `` ` `` (mainly in ruby programs)

Ok, I can use `$HOME` instead of `~`, but there is any Vim specific way (maybe some keystroke sequence) to enter these (and other) "special" chars non present in keyboard available?

Solution could be a key-binding in `.vimrc`?
By example I have in my `.vimrc` this:

```
map ' `
```

but as you can imagine I'm unhappy with this specific key remap...( and I have `<Fx>` already occupied)

BTW, Maybe the question is a bit off-topic because it is not related to Vim directly, but to the keyboard hw/ language setting; maybe ask in Stack Overflow is better?

Comment: How many keystrokes are you willing to dedicate? Since you're using Ubuntu, you can always use Unicode: Ctrl-Shift-u, then `7E` will give you `~`, Ctrl-Shift-u, then `60` will give you `\``.

Comment: thx, but It seems not working. plese note I use an headless ubuntu through a remote terminal (putty)...

Comment: Try from insert mode: `Ctrl-v u 007e`

Comment: @VanLaser yes it works! voted

Comment: You can now use something like: `inoremap <leader>t <C-v>u007e`, 
`inoremap <leader>' <C-v>u0060` etc. to create insert mode maps. Just search for the Unicode values for the special characters you want mapped, as @muru mentioned. *Note*: don't use those maps if your `<leader>` is `<Space>` :D

Comment: That can be expedited by looking at `man ascii` on Ubuntu.

Comment: @GiorgioRobino - what happens if you hit `AltGr ^` and `AltGr '` combos ? Reference: http://superuser.com/a/667654/292962

Comment: @Vanlaser nothing happens :-(

Comment: Instead digraphs solution works. thx @8bittree

Answer (score 11):

From [`:help digraph`](https://vimhelp.org/digraph.txt.html#digraph):

> Digraphs are used to enter characters that normally cannot be entered by
> an ordinary keyboard.

Running [`:digraphs`](https://vimhelp.org/digraph.txt.html#%3Adigraphs) will show you the currently defined digraphs. `` ` `` is defined as `'!` and `~` is defined as `'?`.

There are two ways of entering digraphs:

```
<C-k> {char1} {char2}
{char1} <BS> {char2}
```

The second method requires [`:set digraph`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27digraph%27).

---

That said, `` inoremap '' ` ``  might be quicker, assuming you don't often need two `'`s in a row. Note that globally remapping `''` will mask [`:help ''`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%27%27), but mapping it in insert and command modes is safe to my knowledge. Off the top of my head, I can't think a similar memorable and convenient alternative for `~`. `--` and `==` seem likely to be used as themselves frequently. Muru's suggestion of `+-` could a good option.

Comment: Ooh! `+-` for tilde! In some contexts, a tilde indicates approximate information, and one could imagine `+-` as having a similar meaning.