# How do you map the back tick character (`) with a modifier key like ctrl?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

Is there a way I can map a `digraph` like  <kbd>`</kbd> , with modifier key like  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  together in vim like this NERDTree bind.

`map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>`

It seems to be a tad bit more complicated when your trying map a digraph, and at first I thought I found my solution when I came across these

- [How to enter tilde (~), back tick (`) and special
  chars with a  non-US keyboard ?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4855/how-to-enter-tilde-back-tick-and-special-chars-with-a-non-us-keyboard/)
- [Vim Documentation: Key Notations](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#key-notation/)
- `:h digraph-table`

Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to get it syntatically correct. I want a map to open my `~/.vimrc`, anyway I could do this ?

Comment: No, not in Vim.

Comment: @romainl Ah.. not possible ? That's unfortunate...

Comment: Indeed; details: [Vim FAQ 20.4](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.4) and [Vim FAQ 20.5](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.5)

Comment: I wish I came across that sooner, was spending a good minute trying to figure out something that's not possible. Thanks guys!